# A question on the Haar basis for $L_{1}[0,1]$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(x_{n})_{n=1}^\infty$ be a basis for a Banach space $X$. It is important to know the exact expression of the norm of $\|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}x_{i}\|$ for all $n$ and all scalars $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}$. For example, if $(s_{n})_{n}$ is the summing basis of $c_{0}$, then $$\Big\|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}s_{i}\Big\|=\max_{1\leq k\leq n}\Big|\sum_{i=k}^{n}a_{i}\Big|;$$ If $(e_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is the unit vector basis of $c$ ($e_{0}=(1,1,1,\ldots)$), then $$\Big\|\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}e_{i}\Big\|=\max\big(|a_{0}|,|a_{0}+a_{1}|,\ldots,|a_{0}+a_{n}|\big).$$ These expressions are quite useful. My concern is the expression of $\|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}h_{i}\|$, where $(h_{n})_{n}$ is the Haar basis for $L_{1}[0,1]$.

Question 1. $\|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}h_{i}\|=$ ?

Question 2. $\|\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}f_{i}\|=$ ?, where $(f_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is the Faber-Schauder basis for $C[0,1]$.

Thank you !

Comment: What do you get for $\|\sum_{i=1}^{2}a_{i}h_{i}\|$ and $\|\sum_{i=1}^{3}a_{i}h_{i}\|$ ?

Comment: Haar basis is usually indexed by two indices as $h_{j,k}$, $j\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. It might be helpful to use double indices.

Comment: @OnurOktay  You are right. I shall use double indices.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar   I shall first consider $\|\sum_{i=1}^{2}a_{i}h_{i}\|$ and $\|\sum_{i=1}^{3}a_{i}h_{i}\|$, and then by induction, maybe...